# Handoff webpages in Safari from iPhone to MacBook without the Dock

Tags: macos, iphone, safari, mojave, continuity

I have a webpage loaded on my iPhone. Now I want it in Safari on my MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid-2015).

The only way I found so far: Click the icon in the Dock (on my MacBook). But I don't want to use the Dock.

How can I Handoff a webpage from my iPhone to my MacBook without needing to look at the Dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a feature called iCloud Tabs.

- [Set up and use iCloud Tabs](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202530)

> iCloud keeps the tabs you have open in Safari up to date on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Mac. That means you can go from one device to the next and pick up browsing wherever you left off.

Once you have iCloud Tabs setup, simply launch Safari on your MacBook and go to Safari Menu bar → View → Show Tab Overview, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

The web pages open in Safari on all your linked devices are listed just below the tabs open in the current window.

[image]

The iCloud Tabs are listed just below all the open tabs in the current Safari window, so you may have to a bit of scrolling if you have a lot of tabs open in Safari on your Mac.

The beauty of iCloud Tabs is that it also works the other way round. You can easily open pages from your Mac on your iPhone. This comes in handy especially since iPhone (unlike iPad) doesn't show a Handoff icon in the Dock.

Answer (score 0):

The handoff icon appears in the app switcher, which is activated by command-tab:

[image]